# Service Principal Creation by Terraform doesn't provide password/secret in the output

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, service-principal

when generating Service Principal in Azure [manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal#manually-create-a-service-principal), as a result of the operation I'm provided a password.

It's not the case however if I create service principal with Terraform, the password is not among the outputs of this module:

```
  + azuread_service_principal.k8s_principal
      id:                <computed>
      application_id:    "${azuread_application.app.application_id}"
      display_name:      <computed>
```

Is there anything I missed? Why does the Terraform behavior differs in the output compared to CLI?

Comment: wire password into other place, or get password as data to be wired into other places, or look at state file - here it is. you cannot export it, it will give <sensitive>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to who using newer version of Terraform, you don't need to preset the password, following code is working fine:

```
    resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "auth_pwd" {
      service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.auth.id
    }
    
    output "auth_client_secret" {
      value = azuread_service_principal_password.auth_pwd.value
      description = "output password"
      sensitive = true
    }
```

then you can run the following cli to retrieve the password:

```
terraform output -raw auth_client_secret
```

tested on terraform 1.0.10, hashicorp/azuread provider 2.11

Answer (score 8):

`password` is required INPUT to the [azuread_service_principal_password](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/r/service_principal_password.html) block.  As such, you can generate a random password and export it yourself.  Complete Terraform code is something like this:

```
resource "azuread_application" "app" {
  name = "${local.application_name}"
}

# Create Service Principal
resource "azuread_service_principal" "app" {
  application_id = "${azuread_application.app.application_id}"
}

resource "random_string" "password" {
  length  = 32
  special = true
}

# Create Service Principal password
resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "app" {
  end_date             = "2299-12-30T23:00:00Z"                        # Forever
  service_principal_id = "${azuread_service_principal.app.id}"
  value                = "${random_string.password.result}"
}

output "sp_password" {
  value = "${azuread_service_principal_password.app.value}"
  sensitive = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the terraform document, the [azuread_service_principal](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/r/service_principal.html) block only defines the Argument `application_id`  and Attributes `id`, `display_name`, So you only could see these resources. Also, the [azuread_service_principal_password](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/r/service_principal_password.html) block allows you to export the Key ID for the Service Principal Password. You still could not see the real password.

In the Azure CLI [az ad sp create-for-rbac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac) has an optional parameter --Password. So you could see the password output.

Comment: You basically confirmed my observations. Thank you. Also +1 for the `azuread_service_principal_password` information.